# AngularJS Material - Show/hide elements with md-option

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I'm trying to build a dropdown menu with checkboxes that show/hide certain elements when cheked/unchecked using AngularJS Material.

Normally I'd use `md-checkbox` and a combintion of `ng-model` on the checkbox and `ng-show` on the element to be shown or hidden, but I'm trying to do it with the [Select Header](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select#select-header), as seen on the AngularJS Material website, and it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
<md-select ng-model="filters" multiple>
    <md-select-header>
        <input placeholder="" class="md-text">
    </md-select-header>
    <md-optgroup>
        <md-option ng-value="filter-1" ng-model="showDiv">Attribute</md-option>
        <md-option ng-value="filter-2" ng-model="showOther">Another Attibute</md-option>
    </md-optgroup>
</md-select>

<div ng-show="showDiv || notice.status.visibility">
    This is some content.
</div>
<div ng-show="showOther || notice.status.visibility">
    This is more content.
</div>
```

Any solutions that don't envolve using javascript are most welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it isn't a very elegant solution, I managed to make this work using `ng-click`, as seen below:

```
<md-select ng-model="filters" multiple>
    <md-select-header>
        <input placeholder="" class="md-text">
    </md-select-header>
    <md-optgroup>
        <md-option ng-value="filter-1" ng-click="showDiv = ! showDiv">Attribute</md-option>
        <md-option ng-value="filter-2" ng-click="showOther = ! showOther">Another Attibute</md-option>
    </md-optgroup>
</md-select>

<div ng-show="showDiv || notice.status.visibility">
    This is some content.
</div>
<div ng-show="showOther || notice.status.visibility">
    This is more content.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your option must be a single model,

Do it this way

```
<md-select ng-model="filters" multiple>
    <md-select-header>
        <input placeholder="" class="md-text">
    </md-select-header>
    <md-optgroup>
        <md-option name="filter" ng-value="filter-1" ng-model="showDiv">Attribute</md-option>
        <md-option name="filter" ng-value="filter-2" ng-model="showDiv">Another Attibute</md-option>
    </md-optgroup>
</md-select>
<div ng-show="showDiv == 'filter-1' || notice.status.visibility">
    This is some content.
</div>
<div ng-show="showDiv == 'filter-2' || notice.status.visibility">
    This is more content.
</div>
```

Comment: That didn't do it. I managed to make it work using ng-click, as seen in my answer.